# Quartz.net for multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, database, quartz.net, jobs, job-scheduling

I am using quartz.net for job scheduling. I have a table in my database JobQueue. Quartz.net reads from this JobQueue and executes the jobs. Everything works fine.  Now there is a new requirement that i need to extend the job scheduling for more than one client. This means Quartz.net has to be configured to read from more than one database. How to handle this scenario? I have one service written using Quartz.net which should schedule jobs for multiple clients by reading from their respective databases. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone able to implement this so far?

Answer (score 0):

How sure how it will scale up, but it is possible to create multiple Appdomains and have a different scheduler hosted inside each appdomain.

If you are reading the quartz settings from the app.config file, then you would probably need to change some settings such as the connectionstring at runtime.

Comment: Can you please help with the code for this requirement?